# Clear input when data is entered into another input

Tags: jquery, input

I have a form with a secondary address section. In this section you can fill in either Street or PO box address. I want to ensure that only one address is submitted so I want to clear the other form if a user enters data into the other input field.

My code below is not working, any ideas? Thanks

```
$('#pobox_number').change(function() {
if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $('#street_name_postal').val('');
}
```

Comment: can you put an alert and see if the function is getting called as you type in pobox_number textbox?

Comment: Hi, I tried and the alert didn't run. any suggestions? thanks

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for all the help, I got the code to work by adding input in front of the IDs. Weird but it needed that to target those IDs. If anyone needs points just answer using this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer ended up being very simple, not sure why I needed to target the elements so precisely but adding input before "#street_name_postal" did the trick.

```
$('#pobox_number').change(function() {
if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
$('input#street_name_postal').val('');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming #pobox_number is an input with type text the change event is only fired on blur, so your code might be working but just not as you expect it to.

You could try using the keypress event instead so your code would look like this:

```
$('#pobox_number').keypress(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $('#street_name_postal').val('');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work if the elements' IDs are correct. Work = clean the value for the other field.

But, if you don't want to send inputs (even if it is empty) content, you should make sure that the `name` attribute for these elements are empty, if no `name` attribute is set, no data is send.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks ok, except for the missing closing parenthesis for `change`. You should have:

```
$('#pobox_number').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $('#street_name_postal').val('');
    }
});
```

Here's a working [jsFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/bfq6q/1/).

That said, I would suggest using `blur` instead, otherwise it's possible for the user to go back and forth between fields, and if the value hasn't changed then the event won't be triggered. Here's an [example of the `blur` approach](http://jsfiddle.net/bfq6q/).